# Webpack babel-loader with 'stage-0' and 'es2015' presets doesn't recognise import statement

Tags: webpack

With config

`module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/src",
    entry: "./main",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          presets: ['react', 'stage-0', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
}`

(tried to remove stage-0 also)

I have `Line 8: Unexpected token ... You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` error in src/main.js where line 8 is first line after comment:

`/*! @preserve
 *
 * The MIT License (MIT)
 *
 * 
 *
 */
import t from './'`

Presets are installed, webpack version in node_modules is `1.12.11`.

Comment: "Unexpected token ..."? is this "..." is actual part of the error message or you just cut off a part of it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a module to import. You just provided a directory.

Comment: /\.jsx?$/ matches files ending with .js or .jsx.  The ? operator makes the x optional.

Comment: @ZakPatterson valid point! I'm not up to date on my Regex. I can only assume one more thing, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It's actually a library code, so I don't have access to `import t from './'`. They seem to build it somehow though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the order between `stage-0` and `es2015`, just like this:

```
presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
```